# Object key value corrupted

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

Good day

The following code is used in a Laravel framework to return data from our server:

```
$ses = DB::connection('odbc')
            ->table('HBO.SM200T')
            ->where('USRPF1', '=', strtoupper(auth()->user()->name))
            ->first();
```

But on one of my pc's it returns my data fine as below:

```
{#780 ▼
  +"WAGWRD": "VTER"
  +"PERSNR": "56846"
  +"STELS": "59"
  +"TAK": "324"
  +"BESKR": "                              "
  +"STVDAT": "99999999"
  +"TAALN": "2"
  +"USRPF1": "AV        "
  +"USRPF2": "          "
}
```

But on my new installation of Fedora 24 it returns as:

```
{#783 ▼
  +b"W\x00‚«\x14V": "VTER"
  +b"P\x00‚«\x14V": "56846"
  +"S\x00\x00\x00\x00": "59"
  +b"T\x00»": "324"
  +b"B\x00ƒ«\x14": "                              "
  +b"S\x00ƒ«\x14V": "99999999"
  +b"T\x00ƒ«\x14": "2"
  +b"U\x00ƒ«\x14V": "          "
}
```

It looks like the Key of the pair is not decoded correctly?

Does anyone know of a solution.

Thanks in advance.