# Strange behavior fetching some data from SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, laravel, eloquent, xampp, query-builder

I am having a problem while trying to get specific data from SQL Server, I am using the following query:

```
$rooms = DB::connection('conn')->select("
    select 
        sum(TotalDia) as TotalDia, 
        avg(PorcentajeDia) as PorcentajeDia, 
        sum(TotalMes) as TotalMes, 
        avg(PorcentajeMes) as PorcentajeMes,
        sum(TotalAño) as TotalAño,
        avg(PorcentajeAño) as PorcentajeA
    from EB 
    where Fecha between '2017-04-28' and '2017-04-28' and Rubro = 'R01'")
```

The problem is that I am getting this when dumping $rooms

```
+"Descripcion": "Habitacion"
+"TotalDia": "81405.7300"
+"PorcentajeDia": ".370000"
+"TotalMes": "2206259.4100"
+"PorcentajeMes": ".660000"
+b"TotalAño": "5994822.4900"
+b"PorcentajeAño": ".600000"
```

As you can see the last two columns are retrieved with something with "+b", any one knows what does it mean? this is complicating additional operations like encoding data into json, accesing data and so.
Any help is welcome!

**[UPDATE]**
The problem was very simple actually, basically I just changed the alias from TotalAño to Totalanio and it worked just fine. But it is important to say that the default behavior of select * also puts a +b in the fetched array. Son in this cases it is better to use table aliases.

Comment: Is +b some sort of unicode identifier? Those two columns have a tilde.

Comment: Not a tilde but "ñ"

Comment: Same thing, in English the vergulilla is a tilde... but the point remains! I don't know the answer but it looks like the +b prefix is because of the unicode character. This thread isn't the same issue as you, but look at the formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021288/object-key-value-corrupted the ones with the double arrow unicode character are marked with +b.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I finally solved this problem, your comments were very helpful!